# ASP.NET MVC debug details screen instead of 404 error page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, iis, deployment

I have changed my ASP.NET MVC web.config settings to debug="false":

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
 .....
```

but still after deployment to the server, in case of entering wrong URL I get a Server Error page with Exception Details and Stack Trace instead of standard 404 server error page.

What else have I omitted to turn off debug mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could activate custom errors:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/customerrors/500.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/customerrors/404.html" />
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="/customerrors/403.html" />
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 1):

Turning off debug only removes generation of debug code, it does not change the custom errors mode, which Darin has described how to do.  You need to do both for a release build.